# Xcode not parsing my #import classes

Tags: xcode, class, import

Suddenly, Xcode stopped recognizing my class "Notification," and now its saying that I have to replace Notification with NSNotification. I had this working a few minutes ago, and now I can't even compile the app.

[image: Xcode parsing problem]

Comment: Show your code for `Notification.h`

Answer (score -1):

Solved this.

It turns out that, I don't know why, in my Notification.h I was importing the class in which the problem was appearing.

Example: Class A had an import to class B, and Class B had an import to Class A.